# how to configure joomla pagination to use POST page links

Tags: php, jquery, joomla, pagination

Im using joomla pagination on backend and frontend. But here and here works different:

on backend joomla pagination generate page links like this:

```
  <a href="#" title="2" onclick="document.adminForm.limitstart.value=10; Joomla.submitform();return false;">2</a>
```

and on the front end page links like this:

```
  <a title="1" href="/index.php?option=com_bestevents&amp;view=dco&amp;Itemid=562&amp;limit=10&amp;limitstart=0" class="pagenav">1</a>
```

So:

On the backend click on the page link resulting sending POST to server.

On the frontend click on the page link resulting sending GET to server.

i would like to set on frontend to send POST request not GET. How to fix, change a links on the front end to using javascript onlick event to send form with pagination??

Comment: Why would you want this ? This will keep bots from accessing the pages. Your site won't get indexed in search engines.

Comment: i dont care about indexing pages. It is inner project in my company and dosen`t need to be indexed. I need POST beacuse i using joomla pagination to my own mechanism

Answer (score 0):

If you're using a custom template then you can add pagination.php to your template file.

For example protostar has:

/templates/protostar/html/pagination.php

If you copy that into your template then I guess you can make the pagination similar to how it works in the administrator? You would probably need to modify the pagination_list_render method in this case?

Of course that assumes that your front end pagination is contained within a form and that you are using a template where you can override this file.